# How to get out put parameters of a mysql function in Codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a MySQL procedure `GET_JOB_ID`, output parameter is `job_id`. Then I call it from `codeigniter`

```
$data = $this->db->query("CALL GET_JOB_ID()");
```

Then how can I get the output parameter `job_id` from `codeigniter`?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

```
$job_id = 0;
    $this->load->database();   
    $job_data = $this->db->query("CALL GET_JOB_ID(@job_id)");
    $out_param_query = $this->db->query('select @job_id as job_id;'); 
    foreach ($out_param_query->result() as $key) {
        $job_id = $key->job_id;
    }
    $this->db->close();
```